# Determining the URL of an active Chrome process via Task Manager

Tags: windows, google-chrome, process, task-manager

Given the following screenshot as an example:

[image: screen shot of task manager]

How would you determine which subprocess of Chrome is chewing the most memory? Is this possible with Windows Task Manager (specifically on Windows 7, though other versions are fine, too)? Should a different tool be used, and, if so, which one (free if possible)?

Comment: Do you specifically need it to be with the Windows Task Manager? Because the task manager which is included in Chrome could answer your need.

Comment: @Gnoupi - I'm wanting/needing an external tool, yes - Chrome is merely the example I picked for this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible because Chrome renders pages per tab not by process per tab.

It may use the same process to render multiple tabs. Alhthough you can identify which process of Chrome hogging memory by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to start Chrome's own task manager.

[image: Task Manager]